# SPARQL functions in CONSTRUCT/WHERE

Tags: rdf, sparql, fuseki

I mostly use SPARQL SELECT while working on a query for debugging purposes but in the end I want to use the final result it in a CONSTRUCT way; as I want to work with a graph and not key/value query results.

What I don't get yet (and can't seem to find with search engines/docs) is if I can use functions as well that way. As an example, I use a property path to concatenate titles I get into a "superstring", which I later use for building a Lucene index to increase plain text search quality:

```sql
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>    

SELECT (group_concat(?title ; separator = " ") AS ?fancytitle) WHERE { 
  GRAPH ?graph {
    <http://data.staatsarchiv-bs.ch/id/archivalresource/CH-000027-1/pa-633c-a-312-fasc-163>  dc:relation+ ?relation .
    ?relation dc:title ?title .
  }
}
```

Now I would like to have the same `?fancytitle`as a new triple like

```
<http://data.staatsarchiv-bs.ch/id/archivalresource/CH-000027-1/pa-633c-a-312-fasc-163> <fancytitle> ?fancytitle .
```

So I can store it directly in a new graph. Is this possible? I played with some queries but couldn't manage to get it accepted by the SPARQL processor. FYI I'm using Fuseki.

You can try it out at my [SPARQL Endpoint](http://data.alod.ch/sparql/?outputFormat=table&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0APREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0APREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20prov%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2Fns%2Fprov%23%3E%0APREFIX%20time%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2006%2Ftime%23%3E%0APREFIX%20alod%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.alod.ch%2Falod%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20locah%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.archiveshub.ac.uk%2Fdef%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0APREFIX%20level%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Flevel%3E%0APREFIX%20bs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fbs%3E%0APREFIX%20bar%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fbar%3E%0APREFIX%20ge%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fge%3E%0APREFIX%20ne%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Falod%2Fne%3E%0APREFIX%20dct%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20loc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2007%2Fuwa%2Fcontext%2Flocation.owl%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20(group_concat(%3Ftitle%20%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%20%22)%20AS%20%3Ffancytitle)%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20GRAPH%20%3Fgraph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.staatsarchiv-bs.ch%2Fid%2Farchivalresource%2FCH-000027-1%2Fpa-633c-a-312-fasc-163%3E%20%20dc%3Arelation%2B%20%3Frelation%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Frelation%20dc%3Atitle%20%3Ftitle%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&contentTypeConstruct=text%2Fturtle&contentTypeSelect=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.alod.ch%2Falod%2Fsparql&requestMethod=POST&tabTitle=Query%201)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of my colleague we got it to work, `UNION` and `GROUP BY` are essential. This query puts the string together for all `locah:ArchivalResource` in the graphs:

```
CONSTRUCT
{
  ?archresource skos:hiddenLabel ?supertitle
}
WHERE
{
  SELECT ?archresource  (group_concat(?title ; separator = ", ") AS ?supertitle) WHERE {
    GRAPH ?graph {
      {
        SELECT ?title ?archresource WHERE {
          GRAPH ?graph {
            {
              ?archresource a locah:ArchivalResource ;
              dc:title ?title .
            } UNION
            {
              ?archresource dc:relation+ ?relation .
              ?relation dc:title ?title .
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } GROUP BY ?archresource
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is possible

You can't use expressions directly in a `CONSTRUCT` template but you can assign the variable in the `WHERE` clause either via a `SELECT` expression in a sub-query or using `BIND`.

In your case as `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate it can only be a `SELECT` expression so you just need to put your entire `SELECT` as a sub-query e.g.

```sql
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>    

CONSTRUCT
{
  <http://data.staatsarchiv-bs.ch/id/archivalresource/CH-000027-1/pa-633c-a-312-fasc-163> <http://fancyTitle> ?fancytitle
}
WHERE
{
  SELECT (group_concat(?title ; separator = " ") AS ?fancytitle) WHERE { 
    GRAPH ?graph {
      <http://data.staatsarchiv-bs.ch/id/archivalresource/CH-000027-1/pa-633c-a-312-fasc-163>  dc:relation+ ?relation .
      ?relation dc:title ?title .
    }
  }
}
```

The above works fine on your endpoint

Comment: While I was already using sub-queries in other situations, I didn't think of that, thanks a lot! How would a `BIND` look like for non-aggregate functions?

Comment: Followup question, can I still replace the URI of the resource with a variable in this query? Like `?resource  a locah:ArchivalResource; ` - I get zero results back like this. I would like to execute this on all ArchivalResource