# use aggregates (min, max, avg) in CONSTRUCT query

Tags: aggregate-functions, sparql, semantic-web, querying

Is it possible to use aggregates in a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query? If yes, how?

I have the following (simplified) query which works:

```
CONSTRUCT { 
    ?s ei:number ?number .
}
FROM <http://example.org>
WHERE { 
    ?s ei:number ?number
}
```

However, since `?number` has multiple solutions, I would like to calculate the aggregate. I tried it like this:

```
CONSTRUCT { 
    ?s ei:number AVG(?number) .
}
FROM <http://example.org>
WHERE { 
    ?s ei:number ?number
}
```

The [SPARQL Query Validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) raises the following error:

```
Encountered " "avg" "AVG "" at line 3, column 14.
Was expecting one of:
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
     ...
    "(" ...
     ...
    "[" ...
     ...
```

Hence, my question is: (How) can I use aggregates in SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries?

Comment: You'll need to use a subquery in the WHERE part to use the aggregates, and the construct based on that data.  E.g., does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28427795/1281433) from [SPARQL functions in CONSTRUCT/WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28427219/1281433) work for you?

Comment: Asked and answered on the Jena users list.