# BIND in CONSTRUCT query with sub-SELECT (SPARQL)

Tags: select, bind, sparql, construct

Related to another question (see: [SPARQL functions in CONSTRUCT/WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427219/sparql-functions-in-construct-where)) where the answer leads to having a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query with a aggregate SELECT inside, I now would like to know how to use BIND in this construct.

My current query looks like this (simplified):

```
PREFIXES
CONSTRUCT { ?s rdfs:label ?var . }
WHERE {
    SELECT ?s (AVG(?single) as ?agg) ...
        WHERE {
        ...
        }
    GROUP BY ?s ...
}
```

The question is: Where to place a BIND statement which is used to bind values to variables, which are then used in the CONSTRUCT statement (e.g. `?var`)?

I tried to do it similar as is shown in this message: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201111.mbox/%3C4ED66723.7030506@googlemail.com%3E.
But the difference is, that there is no nested SELECT in this example.

Answer (score 2):

This query composition seems to work for me:

```
PREFIX
CONSTRUCT { ... }
WHERE {
    BIND () {
        SELECT ...
            WHERE {
            ...
            }
        GROUP BY ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the bind(...) part. What are you trying to bind?

Comment: it's just there for simplicity. I try to bind variables from the inner select. I already got some solutions here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201511.mbox/browser

thanks for your help!